# Order by statement after group by is not working in cpanel but worked in localhost

Tags: php, laravel, query-builder

i get this error when i upload it on online cpanel

**Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #1 of ORDER BY clause is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'dreamsch_school_management.students.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by (SQL: select `class`, count(*) as total from `students` group by `class` order by `id` asc)**

in controller i Used

```
        $groups = DB::table('students')
            ->select('class', DB::raw('count(*) as total'))
            ->groupBy('class')
            ->orderBy('id', 'ASC')
            ->get();
```

i want to arrange in assending order by class. in bar chart. but it give error in `order by` line but correctly runs in my localhost. can you please help me with the query. 
**It was my expectation**
[image: It was my expectation]

**but without ordering i get this one**
[image: without ordering]

Please see the labels in the pictures then you can get the errors. now I want to know how can I place ordering by ID or class when I upload my project in cpanel.

Comment: I think there is no business with javascript here. Please remove the `javascript` tag.

Comment: removed........

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error related to only\_full\_group\_by when executing a query in MySql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34115174/error-related-to-only-full-group-by-when-executing-a-query-in-mysql)

Comment: no Brother. my problems are related on laravel query-builder. not with the my sql. thanks for your comments

Comment: as it is stated in the error `ORDER BY clause is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column`  -  you need to change `->orderBy('id', 'ASC')` to `->orderBy('class', 'ASC')`

Comment: hi bro you are saying that in localhost runs correctly so maybe in your server the mysql you have 'strict' => true, database config and in your localhost you have 'strict' => false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to disabled strict mode in your mysql server
just put 'strict' => false in your config/database in the server